# Finding a FolderID using EWS

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchangewebservices

I want to move an email from one folder to another. I know I need to find the folder ID. That's where my issue is. I see there is a `FindFolders` method for the inbox, but I just need to find the ID of the folder in the inbox.

```
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")

$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
$s.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($email)

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
$psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;

$items = $inbox.FindItems($inbox.TotalCount)
# this doesn't work
$TargetFolder = $inbox.FindFolders('MyFolder')

foreach ($item in $items.Items) {
    $item.Move($TargetFolder)
}
```

I also looked up the `FolderID` using VB in Outlook. But this didn't work either. I think I need to find the ID through PowerShell?

```
$TargetFolder = '00000000DBDD150E618BD0489CDE09859DC24F7A0100949BEDD21F6B4245BEEA6999720A0B090013516500830000'
$item.Move($TargetFolder)
```

I added the `using namespace` and converted the to `Data.FolderID`. However, I get an error that it wants it to be a well known folder. I created a customer main folder.

```
$TargetFolder = '00000000DBDD150E618BD0489CDE09859DC24F7A0100949BEDD21F6B4245BEEA6999720A0B090013516500830000'
$id = [Data.FolderId]::new($TargetFolder)
$item.Move($id.UniqueId)
```

I get these errors:

> Cannot convert argument "`destinationFolderName`", with value: "`00000000DBDD150E618BD0489CDE09859DC24F7A0100949BEDD21F6B4245BEEA6999720A0B090013516500830000`", for "`Move`" to type "`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName`":
>
> Cannot convert value "`00000000DBDD150E618BD0489CDE09859DC24F7A0100949BEDD21F6B4245BEEA6999720A0B090013516500830000`" to type "`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName`".
>
> Error: "Unable to match the identifier name `00000000DBDD150E618BD0489CDE09859DC24F7A0100949BEDD21F6B4245BEEA6999720A0B090013516500830000` to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
>
> Calendar, Contacts, DeletedItems, Drafts, Inbox, Journal, Notes, Outbox, SentItems, Tasks, MsgFolderRoot, PublicFoldersRoot, Root, JunkEmail, SearchFolders, VoiceMail,
>   RecoverableItemsRoot, RecoverableItemsDeletions, RecoverableItemsVersions, RecoverableItemsPurges, ArchiveRoot, ArchiveMsgFolderRoot, ArchiveDeletedItems,
>   ArchiveRecoverableItemsRoot, ArchiveRecoverableItemsDeletions, ArchiveRecoverableItemsVersions, ArchiveRecoverableItemsPurges, SyncIssues, Conflicts, LocalFailures,
>   ServerFailures, RecipientCache, QuickContacts, ConversationHistory, ToDoSearch""
>
> ```
> At C:\Users\jpb\Desktop\literatum\literatum.ps1:261 char:1
> + $item.Move($id.UniqueId)
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
> ```

When I try your code with my login way I still error out.

```
Using namespace "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices"

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$MailAddress
)

# need to download this!!!!!!!!!!!!
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")

$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
$s.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($MailAddress)
$objExchange = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::msgFolderRoot)  ###Inbox

<#
    Define Extended properties
    PR_FOLDER_TYPE: Contains a constant that indicates the folder type.
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815373.asp
    PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED: Contains the sum, in bytes, of the sizes of all properties on a message object.
    int64 version of PR_MESSAGE_SIZE
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839933.aspx
    PR_DELETED_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED: Could not find official reference.
    PR_FOLDER_PATH: Could not find official reference.
#>
$PR_FOLDER_TYPE = [Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition]::new(13825,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
$PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3592,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Long);
$PR_DELETED_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26267,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Long);
$PR_FOLDER_PATH = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26293, [Data.MapiPropertyType]::String);

$folderIDCount = [Data.FolderId]::new([Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailAddress)

# Define the FolderView used for Export. Should not be any larger then 1000 folders due to throttling
$folderView = [Data.FolderView]::new(1000)

# Deep Traversal will ensure all folders in the search path are returned
$folderView.Traversal = [Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep;
$ewsPropertySet = [Data.PropertySet]::new([Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)

# Add Properties to the  Property Set
$ewsPropertySet.Add($PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED);
$ewsPropertySet.Add($PR_FOLDER_PATH);
$folderView.PropertySet = $ewsPropertySet;

# Exclude any Search Folders in the filter
$searchFilter = [Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo]::new($PR_FOLDER_TYPE,"1")

# The Do loop will handle any paging that is required if there are more the 1000 folders in a mailbox
do {
    $filterResult = $objExchange.FindFolders($folderIDCount, $searchFilter, $folderView)
    foreach ($singleFolder in $filterResult.Folders) {
        # Try to get the FolderPath Value and then covert it to a usable String
        $folderPathValue = $null
        $singleFolder.TryGetProperty($PR_FOLDER_PATH, [ref]$folderPathValue) | Out-Null

        # Output folder object to pipeline
        $singleFolder | Select-Object Id,DisplayName,@{Name="FolderPath";Expression={$folderPathValue}},FolderClass,ParentFolderId
    }
    $folderView.Offset += $filterResult.Folders.Count
} while($filterResult.MoreAvailable)
```

I get this error for the `FindFolders` method:

> Cannot find an overload for "`FindFolders`" and the argument count: "`3`".
>
> ```
> At line:50 char:9
> +         $filterResult = $objExchange.FindFolders($folderIDCount, $sea ...
> +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
> ```

I can connecting for `$objExchange` and I get these values and more:

```
Id              : AAMkADk5ZDNmODk2LTk0NzAtNDZkNi05Mjk1LTNhMjNlYmYzNzg1ZAAuAAAAAADb3RUOYYvQSJzeCYWdwk96AQD+Gq9HeAtSSLFM1nhOxNIuAAAAMAqcAAA=
ParentFolderId  : AAMkADk5ZDNmODk2LTk0NzAtNDZkNi05Mjk1LTNhMjNlYmYzNzg1ZAAuAAAAAADb3RUOYYvQSJzeCYWdwk96AQD+Gq9HeAtSSLFM1nhOxNIuAAAAMAqbAAA=
ChildFolderCount: 20
```

Comment: `.Move()` has 2 overloads. The first wants a FolderID. the Other is looking for WKFN. It seems that you are not passing a folderID so it is assuming that you are using the other overload.

Comment: What if you change `$item.Move( $id.UniqueId)` -> `$item.Move($id)`. `$id.UniqueId` would be a string whereas `$id` is a `Data.FolderID` which should satisfy the `.Move()`

Comment: When I use $item.Move($id) it says Exception calling "Move" with "1" argument(s): "Id is malformed.". For the data, the FolderName, Mailbox, and ChangeKey are empty. Only the UniqueId as the value which I set.

Comment: 2010 and 2007 are dI fferent then. My code is based on 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is going to be a little more information here than required but I want to show how I get this information in my cmdlets that I made for interacting with my mailbox.

If you look at the [overloads for `FindFolders()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.findfolders%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) they want more than just a string to get the results you are looking for. My example below uses the last overload

> ```
> FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName, SearchFilter, FolderView)
> ```
>
> Searches a well-known folder by using a specified search filter and a specified folder view.

This is a function I have to get me *all* folders in a mailbox.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$MailAddress
)

# Create a reference to Exchange 2010 to match our current environment.
$objExchange = Connect-ExchangeService -MailAddress $MailAddress -DefaultCredentials

<#
    Define Extended properties  
    PR_FOLDER_TYPE: Contains a constant that indicates the folder type.
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815373.asp
    PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED: Contains the sum, in bytes, of the sizes of all properties on a message object. int64 version of PR_MESSAGE_SIZE
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839933.aspx
    PR_DELETED_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED: Could not find official reference.
    PR_FOLDER_PATH: Could not find official reference.
#>
$PR_FOLDER_TYPE = [Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition]::new(13825,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Integer)
$PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3592,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Long);  
$PR_DELETED_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26267,[Data.MapiPropertyType]::Long);  
$PR_FOLDER_PATH = New-Object Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26293, [Data.MapiPropertyType]::String);  

$folderIDCount = [Data.FolderId]::new([Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot,$MailAddress)  

# Define the FolderView used for Export. Should not be any larger then 1000 folders due to throttling  
$folderView = [Data.FolderView]::new(1000)

# Deep Traversal will ensure all folders in the search path are returned  
$folderView.Traversal = [Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep;  
$ewsPropertySet = [Data.PropertySet]::new([Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)

# Add Properties to the  Property Set  
$ewsPropertySet.Add($PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED);  
$ewsPropertySet.Add($PR_FOLDER_PATH);  
$folderView.PropertySet = $ewsPropertySet;

# Exclude any Search Folders in the filter
$searchFilter = [Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo]::new($PR_FOLDER_TYPE,"1")  

#The Do loop will handle any paging that is required if there are more the 1000 folders in a mailbox  
do {  
    $filterResult = $objExchange.FindFolders($folderIDCount, $searchFilter, $folderView)       
    foreach($singleFolder in $filterResult.Folders){              
        #Try to get the FolderPath Value and then covert it to a usable String
        $folderPathValue = $null     
        $singleFolder.TryGetProperty($PR_FOLDER_PATH, [ref]$folderPathValue) | Out-Null

        # Output folder object to pipeline
        $singleFolder | Select-Object Id,DisplayName,@{Name="FolderPath";Expression={$folderPathValue}},FolderClass,ParentFolderId
    } 
    $folderView.Offset += $filterResult.Folders.Count
}while($filterResult.MoreAvailable)
```

`Connect-ExchangeService` is just a function that does more or less what your first few lines are doing. Using `FindFolders()` I search from the root folder and return all folders with some custom properties into `$filterResult`. `$filterResult` now contains information about each folder. Specifically their ID's.

So down the line if I wanted to move a mail item to another folder I could do something like this.

```
$targetFolderID = ($folders | Where-Object{$_.Displayname -eq $sourceFolder}).ID.UniqueID
$item.Move($targetFolderID)
```

Plenty of the EWS parameters want a typedID, not just a string. In you last example I think that should have triggered an error stating something similar. Either way if you have a string cast it like this to get something EWS will work with

```
$id = [Data.FolderId]::new($targetFolderID)
```

You might notice that the type names here are shorter. I have `Using namespace "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices"` in my script to keep my line length down.

### Extra reading

I had a tough time getting my head wrapped around EWS. [This blog](http://gsexdev.blogspot.ca/2012/01/ews-managed-api-and-powershell-how-to_23.html) helped immensely with many example showing how its done. The author is also a member here that frequently answers EWS questions.

Comment: I will look into the blog later. I tried converted the ID into the data.FolderID. But for the move method, it was expecting type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName". However, I thought the move Method would accept a custom folder I created.

Comment: I have a task that moved mail for me every 5 minutes to a custom folder. I know this is supposed to work. Let me check my code and yours to see if I omitted something.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/f60bcab6-b936-4b63-896c-05bf6d6ee0c0/ews-not-returning-user-created-folders?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: I think its because my custom folder is not a sub folder of inbox but at a parallel level. I found the link above  which talks about it. I will explore it then come back with answers... Also they do a bind of $rootFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot)  ... which i think allows the method move to be for generic folders as well.

Comment: My code above works from `msgFolderRoot` as well. So yes, that would be an issue for you. Let me know how that implementation works.

Comment: I tried out your code but replaced your login with my version. I still got errors for the findFolders method

Comment: the ids created from strings and the ones created from FindFolders are different. They work just the same for me. If the findfolders process worked you could just take the id object straight from that.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it all. Thanks so much for the help! I added my new code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So I tried a new way of Travel Deep for finding the Folder starting at `msgFolderRoot`.

```
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
$s.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($MailAddress)
#$objExchange = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::msgFolderRoot)  ###Inbox

$objExchange = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::msgFolderRoot)  ###Inbox

$fv = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView]100
$fv.Traversal = 'Deep'
$objExchange.Load()

$folders = $objExchange.FindFolders($fv)|select DisplayName,ID
$folders = $objExchange.FindFolders($fv)

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    if ($folder.DisplayName -eq 'LiteratumLicenseInventoryReportArchive') {
        $folderMoveTo = $folder;
    }
}

$folderMoveTo
```

Then I find the email by searching the inbox, then convert the Folder to the FolderID and Move that email.

```
$s = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2007_SP1)
$s.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials

# discover the url from your email address
$s.AutodiscoverUrl($email)

$inbox = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($s,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox) 

# create a property set (to let us access the body & other details not available from the FindItems call)
$psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;

$items = $inbox.FindItems($inbox.TotalCount)

foreach ($item in $items.Items) {
    $item.load($psPropertySet)
    if ($item.Subject.Contains('Subject Test')) {
        $convertedFolder = [Data.FolderId]::new($folderMoveTo.Id)
        $item.Move($convertedFolder)
        break 
    }
}
```